# API Gateway Error on GCP : API Gateway Management Service Agent does not have permission to create Service Configs for Service

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam, api-gateway

Getting the error "**API Gateway Management Service Agent does not have permission to create Service Configs for Service**", while creating a API Gateway on GCP. The API gets created but not the gateway. How do I fix this ? I personally have OWNER level access on the project and I am using compute engine service account for API Gateway ( which has editor access). What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this? I am facing exactly the same issue.

Comment: I also have this problem? Did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You could review if your  API Gateway service account has the the roles

--role roles/apigateway.serviceAgent

--role roles/apigateway_management.serviceAgent

You can find more info about the roles in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-agents)